# Is 'means of' a prepositional verb?

Tags: prepositional-verbs

In the sentence: "*Rough and ready does not refer to time, but **means of** low or poor quality.*"

Is '**means of**' a prepositional verb?

I searched for it in the internet but I didn't find a full reference for prepositional verbs and also 'mean of' wasn't in the available lists.

Comment: "Rough and ready does not refer to time, but means **of low or poor quality**." - You split the sentence at the wrong place.

Comment: This is a good place to use a definite article: _**the** means of_. That would mark _means_ as a noun and not a verb, which is a good start.

Comment: [**Rough and ready**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/rough_and_ready) has a different shade of meaning to "poor quality". It means something made from whatever is to hand, without implying that it is necessarily a poor solution – it may well be a very good solution under the circumstances it was made.

Comment: I think "means" is a verb. I would recast the sentence as "Rough and ready does not refer to time; rather it means (of) low or poor quality".

Comment: The verbal meaning can be brought out in "rough and ready does not refer to time --     
 rough and ready means (of) low or poor quality."

Comment: "Rough and ready" does not refer to time, but means "of low or poor quality". Some quote marks would clarify it.

Comment: Or to clarify the alternate interpretation: *Rough and ready does not refer to time, but [refers] **to** means of low or poor quality.*

Comment: Googling the sentence took me to a book "English Idioms in Use". Looking at the parts available shows they use bold type to identify the phrases under discussion, not quotes. Unfortunately, this particular example is hiding behind the subscribe wall, so I'll  never know.